# RAILS - Force where condition in ActiveRecord model for .save and .update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I partitioned my table postgres table by a column called account_id

When making queries, I have a gem that uses the default_scope and add the where automatically and that's great but I need the where condition in model.save and model.update too.

I read that default scopes don't trigger for model updates, is there anything I can do to add this where in the save and update statements of a model?

Example:

`Model.update(name: "X)` generates: update model set name = "X" where id = '1'

but I need this:

`Model.update(name: "X)` to generate: update model set name = "X" where id = '1' and account_id = model.account_id

I tried like this: `Model.where(id: model.id).update_all(name: "X)` and it works but I would need to change many many things in the application.

Im using rails6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you need what is essentially a composite primary key in the first place? Why can't you just use the fact that the id is unique in the scope of its own table?

Comment: There is a [gem which provides CPK's](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys) but with all due respect to its authors I would really good reason to add a dependency which breaks with every new Rails release.

Comment: Max I think that would work for me, but yes, having these kind of dependencies, give me chills.

Comment: Max I need composite pks because i partitioned the table by a column i have called account_id, so if I don't use this column for every action in the database, postgres does a full scan everytime.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `Model.update` and `Model.update_all` are very different, e.g. the latter ignores any validations and callbacks you might have.

Secondly, `Model.update` expects ID or array of IDs to be passed as a first argument, if you don't pass it - it assumes `:all` IDs, check out the implementation:

```rb
def update(id = :all, attributes)
  if id.is_a?(Array)
    # [cut for clarity]
  elsif id == :all
    all.each { |record| record.update(attributes) } #<--- HERE
  else
    # [more cut off for clarity
```

So `Model.update` is not supposed to work with any other conditions, because it expects the actual primary keys to be passed to it.

> I tried like this: Model.where(id: model.id).update_all(name: "X) and it works
> Yes, but under the hood the framework does very different operation than `update` and you might not want that. Do this instead:

```rb
Model.update(Model.where(YOUR_CONDITION_HERE).ids, name: 'X')
```

(Your question is not really clear on what the condition should be).

```
but I would need to change many many things in the application.
```

Well, some refactorings are like that.

!BELOW IS NOT RECOMMENDED, FOR EDUCATIONAL PURPOSES ONLY!

There is a way to make `Model.update(name: "X)` work as you expect it to work, but this will change the behavior of the method (it will be a different method for the Model, and behave inconsistently for all other models):

```rb
class Model < ApplicationRecord
  def self.update(attributes)
    where(YOUR_CONDITION_HERE).update_all(attributes)
  end
end
```

Please don't do it, you'll make your codebase worse.

Comment: Thanks Gzergorz, gonna do some more study, but as Active record has problems to work with composite pk's, the partition strategy I used for PG may not be the best option, gonna try to partition my tables by schema or different databases and see the result